# How to combine multiple columns from different as columns in to one table or view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am having a table with shop ids and their sales. Structure is like

**Shops**

```
Shop_id (int)  |  Sell (time)
```

I want to get result in following format:

```
Shop Id, Monday sales, Tuesday sales, ....., Sunday Sales.
```

I am getting sales for a particular day by following query.

```
declare @day table( id int, sale time)

INSERT INTO @day ( id,sale) 
SELECT   s.Shop_id as id ,s.sell as sale 
FROM Shops as s left join Shops as s2 on s.[Shop_id] = s2.[Shop_id]
```

But after that, I am not able to combine that.
I tried different joins but results are repeated instead of putting null.
I tried the following query but it is not working.

```
SELECT ( SELECT sale FROM @day1 )as MONDAY,( SELECT sale FROM @day2 ) as TUESDAY
```

Please, let me know if there is any other way to combine things.

The out put should look like below.

**Weekly Sales**

```
_______________________________________________________________
|  id   |   Monday    |   Tuesday     |  Wednesday    | ...| Sunday  |
_______________________________________________________________
|   1   | 10:00:00  AM | 09:00:00  AM |  Null         |....| Null    |
|   1   | 12:00:00  AM | 01:30:00  PM |  Null         |....| Null    |
|   2   | 09:00:00  AM |  Null        |  11:00:00  AM |....| Null    |
|   2   | 11:00:00  AM |  Null        |  11:30:00  AM |....| Null    |
|   2   | 11:30:00  PM |  Null        |  01:00:00  PM |....| Null    |
|   3   | 10:00:00  AM | 06:00:00  PM |  02:00:00  PM |....| Null    |
|   3   | 10:00:00  PM | 07:30:00  PM |  02:30:00  PM |....| Null    |
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, you can use the nested queries as the example you provided, but you would need to add a `WHERE` clause to get each day. Are you trying to get the total sales for the day? You might not even need the "day" table, you could run the queries to give you the `SUM()` for each day, here is an example:

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(sale) FROM Shops
   WHERE Shop_id = [SHOP_ID]
   AND Sell = [mm/dd/yyyy) AS monday,
   ... AS tuesday, ...,
```

Do that for each day to get the rest of the days. You may need to tweak the query, I'm working with limited knowledge and information about your project.

The other thing that I would look at would be to write a "pivot table" Prepared Statement. This way you can easily use it and just pass needed arguments to it and get a result.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I need time of transactions as lists not the sum or count. And one more thins, This query, SELECT ( SELECT * FROM *),... gives blank columns.

Answer (score 1):

We have the answer for you @ParekhAbhishekN

```
SELECT Shop_id, [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday],    [Saturday], [Sunday]
FROM (
SELECT Shop_id, DATENAME(dw, sell) AS DayWeek,convert(time,sell) time_,Shop_id id,ROW_NUMBER() over(Order by shop_id) r_num
FROM Shops
) AS src
pivot (
MAX(time_) FOR DayWeek IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday])
) AS pvt
```